# Tasks created in Workflow do not appear in My site

Tags: workflow, tasks

We have the My Tasks portion working fine for aggregating tasks from our Sharepoint sites when users create the tasks inside the browser.  I created a workflow to create tasks and assign them to users which seems to be working fine.  The only problem is that none of the tasks that are created during the workflow show up in the user's My Tasks aggregation page.

Search is on a continuous crawl, Work Management is using the same account as the My Site application pool and tasks appear in the My Tasks page if users go through SP and create the tasks, so I know Work Management is working.

I have tried running the workflow in regular mode and in an app step but I still don't see them aggregated.  I can go to the workflow list and see all the tasks created and I've even waited 24 hours, but they never show up.

Anyone ever create tasks inside a workflow and have them show up in your My Tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Task List where we were keeping the tasks was a system provisioned List.  Creating another task List and updating the workflow to store the tasks there made things appear just fine.

Couldn't find a setting in the system provisioned List that would prevent it from being searched.  I even went as far as giving everyone complete rights over it and it still wouldn't work.